# Expression based Autowire in Spring Boot (with Kotlin)

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin, spring-el

## Situation

I'm trying to come up with a methodology to conditionally load one bean (based on the existence of  2 property or environment variables) and if they are missing load up another bean.

## Vars

So the two property (or env vars) are:

- `ProtocolHOST`
- `ProtocolPORT`

So for example `java -jar xxxx  -DProtocolHost=myMachine -DProtocolPort=3333` would use the bean I want, but if both are missing then you'd get another bean.

```
@Component("Protocol Enabled")
class YesBean : ProtocolService {}

@Component("Protocol Disabled")
class NoBean : ProtocolService {
```

Later in my controller I have a:

```
@Autowired
private lateinit var sdi : ProtocolService
```

So I've looked at a variety of options:

using both `@ConditionalOnProperty` and `@ConditionalOnExpression` and I cant seem to make any headway.

I'm pretty sure I need to go the **Expression** route so I wrote some test code that seems to be failing:

```
@PostConstruct
fun customInit() {
    val sp = SpelExpressionParser()
    val e1 = sp.parseExpression("'\${ProtocolHost}'")
    println("${e1.valueType}   ${e1.value}")
    println(System.getProperty("ProtocolHost")
}
```

Which returns:

> class java.lang.String   ${ProtocolHost} 
>   taco

So I'm not sure if my **SPeL** Parsing is working correctly because it looks like its just returning the string "${ProtocolHost}" instead of processing the correct value.  I'm assuming this is why all the attempts I've made in the Expression Language are failing - and thus why i'm stuck.

Any assistance would be appreciated!

Thanks

### Update

I did get things working by doing the following

in my main:

```
 val protocolPort: String? = System.getProperty("ProtocolPort", System.getenv("ProtocolPort"))
 val protocolHost: String? = System.getProperty("ProtocolHost", System.getenv("ProtocolHost"))

 System.setProperty("use.protocol", (protocolHost != null && protocolPort != null).toString())
 runApplication<SddfBridgeApplication>(*args)
```

And then on the bean definitions:

```
@ConditionalOnProperty(prefix = "use", name = arrayOf("protocol"), havingValue = "false", matchIfMissing = false)

@ConditionalOnProperty(prefix = "use", name = arrayOf("protocol"), havingValue = "false", matchIfMissing = false)
```

However this feels like a hack and I'm hoping it could be done directly in SpEL instead of pre-settings vars a head of time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a perfect use case for Java based bean configuration:

```
@Configuration
class DemoConfiguration {

    @Bean
    fun createProtocolService(): ProtocolService {
        val protocolPort: String? = System.getProperty("ProtocolPort", System.getenv("ProtocolPort"))
        val protocolHost: String? = System.getProperty("ProtocolHost", System.getenv("ProtocolHost"))
        return if(!protocolHost.isNullOrEmpty() && !protocolPort.isNullOrEmpty()) {
            YesBean()
        } else {
            NoBean()
        }
    }

}

open class ProtocolService

class YesBean : ProtocolService()

class NoBean : ProtocolService()
```

You might also want look into [Externalized Configurations](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html) to replace `System.getProperty()` and `System.getenv()`.

This would then look like this:

```
@Configuration
class DemoConfiguration {

    @Bean
    fun createProtocolService(@Value("\${protocol.port:0}") protocolPort: Int,
                              @Value("\${protocol.host:none}") protocolHost: String): ProtocolService {
        return if (protocolHost != "none" && protocolPort != 0) {
            YesBean()
        } else {
            NoBean()
        }
    }

}
```